# Extremely slow package management after upgrading from package.config to PackageReference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, rider

We have a solution with 300+ projects. They are all .Net framework 4.7. As a preparation for migrating to .Net 5 we replaced the old style package.config with PackageReference and now everything became agonizingly slow. Both with VS 2019 and Rider. Sometimes and for some projects, working with nuget packages seems to work fine, then suddenly it becomes completely unresponsive. We might have to wait several minutes to remove or upgrade a single nuget package.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Both IDE has technical support channels, so use them please. You shouldn't imagine anyone here can analyze a performance issue like that over the internet. You might share more details on the exact steps you did on "we replaced the old style package.config with PackageReference", but again the performance issue might be closed related to your specific environment, so not much to be discussed here.